# Python - loop through list and save state before replacing

Tags: python, list, loops

I'd like to replace the 'x-%' from the origin list with the values from 'anotherList' in loop.
As you can see, when looping through, only the last state is saved, because it replaces the standardList again.

What might be the best way to kind of 'save the state of every list' and then loop through it again?

Result should be:

```
result = ['I', 'just', 'try','to', 'acomplish', 'this','foo', 'list']
```

What I got so for:

```
originList  = ['I', 'x-0', 'x-1','to', 'acomplish', 'x-2','foo', 'x-3']
anotherList = ['just','try','this','list']


for index in originList:
    for num in range(0,4):
        if 'x' in index:
            result = str(originList).replace('x-%s'%(str(num)), anotherList[num])
print result
#['I', 'x-0', 'x-1', 'to', 'acomplish', 'x-2', 'foo', 'list'] <-- wrong :X
```

Thanks for any help because I can't figure it out at the moment

**EDIT*** 
If there is a cleaner solution I would also appreciate to hear

Comment: Can you show what `res` should be like?

Comment: ah sorry result = res

I will edit

Comment: thanks everybody for the nice solutions and quick help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go!

```
>>> for original in originList:
    if 'x' in original:
        res.append(anotherList[int(original[-1])]) #grab the index
    else:
        res.append(original)


>>> res
['I', 'just', 'try', 'to', 'acomplish', 'this', 'foo', 'list']
>>>
```

Since the index of the value needed is in the items of `originList`, you can just use it, so no need for the extra loop. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, thats awesome.
I've been looking for a solution for hours.

Comment: The more hours spent, the better :) Practice makes perfect!

Answer (score 2):

**This one avoids the creation of a new list**

```
count = 0

for word in range(0, len(originList)):
    if 'x-' in originList[word]:
        originList[word] = anotherList[count]
        count += 1

print originList
```

Comment: I think that's also a great solution!

Comment: Thanks @aIKid ! I'm gonna hit up the chat room if you want to join

Answer (score 1):

```
originList  = ['I', 'x-0', 'x-1','to', 'acomplish', 'x-2','foo', 'x-3']
anotherList = ['just','try','this','list']
res = []
i=0
for index in originList:
    if 'x' in index:
        res.append(anotherList[i])
        i += 1
    else:
        res.append(index)

print res
```

you can get right result!
But,I think you have use string.format(like this)

`print '{0}{1}{2}{3}'.format('a', 'b', 'c', 123) #abc123`

Read python docs - [string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
originList  = ['I', 'x-0', 'x-1','to', 'acomplish', 'x-2','foo', 'x-3']
anotherList = ['just','try','this','list']

def change(L1, L2):
    res = []
    index = 0
    for ele in L1:
        if 'x-' in ele:
            res.append(L2[index])
            index += 1
        else:
            res += [ele]
   return res

print(change(originList, anotherList))
```

The result:

```
['I', 'just', 'try', 'to', 'acomplish', 'this', 'foo', 'list']
```